# Import DLL into C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am using C++/CLI for the first time. I am trying to include a DLL into my project (JtToolkit-Library). The Library is only usable in x64.
Now I want to create a C++/CLI project which uses this DLL. And a C# Project which uses the C++/CLI assembly.

My problem is that when I include my headers from the DLL, I get the error: "E1696: C++ Die Datei "Quelle" kann nicht geöffnet werden: "JtTk/JtkCADExporter.h"."
(E1696:  cannot open source file)

When I change the the build configuration to x86, the error goes away and It will find the Header, but can not link with the library, because the library is x64.

I have no idea what is cauing the problem. Is it plausible my C++/CLI template is only working in x86? How can I include the DLL into the project with C++/CLI?

Comment: ***When I change the the build configuration to x86, the error goes away and It will find the Header*** Maybe you did not set the "Additional include directories" setting on all configurations when you added this library to your project.

Comment: I Checked all configuration allready. All Configurations and all Plattforms are set to the same include directory

Comment: Is that folder the one containing the `JtTk` fodler?

Comment: in Additional Include Directories I have the path to the include directory, where the File JtTk is. In there are all headers. This path should work, because i was working with these directories before. The only change to before is, that i am now working in a C++/CLI project and not a C++ project

Comment: It should be the folder that contains the `JtTk` folder so the relative path  `JtTk/JtkCADExporter.h` can work. If its the folder containing `JtkCADExporter.h` that is wrong.

Comment: The directory path is correct. In a simple c++ Project i am able to work. The only change is that I work in a C++/CLI project

Comment: What is "E1696"?  Microsoft C++ compiler errors have the form Cnnnn and do not start with E.  Is this a static analysis error?  Intellisense error?  Have you tried actually running a build to get the errors from the real compiler?